# Cannot connect distinct highcharts points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm extremely new to any javascript/html etc coding, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I'm trying to design a calculator which can project your retirement income based on a number of inputs.  The calculator is working fine, and as part of the outputs I'd like to graph how your retirement income can vary by retirement age.

I've written a little script that populates an array with results [[retire age 1, income 1], [retire age 2, income 2]...etc].  This array in my code is called agePoints I would then like to graph the results using a highcharts line graph.

The problem I'm having is that graph is showing distinct points rather than a line.  I've experimented with a number of solutions, none of which work.

Please help if you can

Code is below:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type:'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Retirement Income',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Income by Retirement Age',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            // axisPoints is an array which contains the retirement ages only
            categories: axisPoints
            min:axisPoints[1],
            title: {
                text: 'Retirement Age'
            }
            //categories: axisPoints

        },
        yAxis: {
            min:0,
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Income'
            },
        },
        legend: {
            enabled:false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },   
        //one thing I tried below to get it to work
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                connectNulls: true
                    }
                    },
        series: [{
            name: 'Projected Income',
            // age points is the array mentioned in my question above
            data: agePoints
        }]
    });
});
```

The chart looks like this:

[image]

The chart looks fine in that the axis are correct and the data is displayed correctly.  However, instead of showing a line, there is a distinct dot for each age point (age on the x-axis).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that your agePoints are sorted by retire age, like this: retire age 1 < retire age 2 < retire age 3 etc.

Comment: I think the agePoints array is already sorted like that.  The first value is your "current age" and each following value increases that age by 1, until age 80.  What suggested that the array wasn't sorted in the right order?

Comment: It's common issue with missing line when data isn't sorted. Also, make sure that all values are numbers, not strings. And last thing - update Highcharts to 3.0.7 (if you have older version).

Comment: Sorry...I somehow accidentally fixed the problem by changing min.axisPoints[1] to min.axisPoints[0].  Not sure why this was causing the problem, but suddenly I have a line going through my graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace missing values in agePoints array with null.

e.g compare these

series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: ['', 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            }, {name: 'Tallinn',
                data: [null, 4.9, 4.5, 4.5, 4.4, 3.5, 2.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]}]

Comment: Thanks.  I think that was the problem.  When initially defining the array I had accidentally given its first value an empty array by putting var agePoints=[[]]; rather than var agePoints=[].  The latter has solved the problem.